# Android SurfaceView resize to fit screen 16:9

Tags: android, resize, surfaceview

**Hello!** Is there a good way of having a 16:9 SurfaceView, and then resize it bigger until it touches a screen edge? (so the SurfaceView is at its biggest size and still 16:9 and not outside the screen)

I have heard it is called letterbox, but havn't found any tutorial about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two relevant sizes, the size of the Surface and the size of the View.

The size of the Surface is determined by the size of the video being rendered to it.  You can't change this.  A 720p video will set the size to 1280x720.

The size of the View is determined by the layout code.  This can be set from within your app.

The system compositor (SurfaceFlinger) will scale the contents of the Surface so they fit in the View.  To avoid distortion, you want to maintain the same aspect ratio.  You do this with a custom [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

For an example, see how [AspectFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java) is used in Grafika's video players, e.g. [this chunk of code](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java#L199).